# Springboot security: not find SecurityContext in HttpSession. Role anonymous. Access denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My hello world war file (Spring boot 3.1.1, jdk 17, jsf) was deployed in Tomcat 10.1.x. My xhtml files are under WEB-INF. Though I used correct username/password (log trace) to login at login.xhtml, the app just stayed at login screen instead of going to a default success url (test.xhtml). The security log trace had "Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]", "HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute." It caused Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS], then Access Denied. Security log trace:

> 533-04:00 DEBUG 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /login
> 543-04:00 DEBUG 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : **POST "/sbwar2/login", parameters={username:[user], password:[password], _csrf:**[9cqHDzmNlsgTvrwCjfBK1gKrEB8YVEBLfuM0Te5Q3Lhh1DjTwq-yPA-49Pk-2t007t1-4TqbPScvN3FmG4YMfNpiut5Rtlvi]}
> 549-04:00 DEBUG 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
> 604-04:00 DEBUG 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
> 604-04:00 TRACE 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
> 608-04:00 DEBUG 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : **Completed 404 NOT_FOUND**
> 609-04:00 TRACE 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : **Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 1204F5B756E65B39DA16CFE184630C21 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute**
> 610-04:00 TRACE 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .**s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]**
> 610-04:00 TRACE 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
> 614-04:00 TRACE 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : **Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=1204F5B756E65B39DA16CFE184630C21], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]**
> ............................
> 651-04:00 TRACE 3980 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=1204F5B756E65B39DA16CFE184630C21], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
> ...................
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: **Access Denied**
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ......................................

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/home","/jakarta.faces.resource/**", "/login", "/login.xhtml").permitAll()               
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                    .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/test.xhtml", true)
                    .failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error-true")      
            )
            .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }   
}
```

login.xhtml

```
    <form action="${request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
    <div align="center"><h:outputLabel styleClass="fa fa-2x" value="Sign in"/></div><br/>                       
    <div align="center">
        <h:outputLabel class="alert alert-danger" value="Invalid user name or password" rendered="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>
    </div>                          
    <div class="input-group input-sm">
        <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="true"  autofocus="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-sm">
        <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="true"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

test.xhtml

```
<h:body>
This is a test
</h:body>
```

I did some research:
[Spring Session - Security Context not found in session after redirect to target url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173817/spring-session-security-context-not-found-in-session-after-redirect-to-target)

[Spring boot Resource Not Found 404 error html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253641/spring-boot-resource-not-found-404-error-html)

[Make JSF resources publicly accessible with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086947/make-jsf-resources-publicly-accessible-with-spring-security)

[SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession and Principal of logged in user is never filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403355/securitycontext-is-empty-or-contents-are-anonymous-context-will-not-be-stored)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/in-memory.html

Update: I tried to add a registry for /login. And rename login.xhtml to signin.xhtml

> 

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Override
   public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
   }
}
```

However, I got 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED for /login

> DEBUG 11512 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /login
> DEBUG 11512 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : **POST "/sbwar2/login", parameters={username:[user], password:[password]**,
> ......
> WARN 11512 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: **Request method 'POST' is not supported**]
> DEBUG 11512 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] **o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED**

Update: I added this class. It worked.

```
   @Controller
   public class LoginController {
      @GetMapping("/login")
      String login() {
         return "signin.xhtml";
      } 
    }
```

Comment: `Completed 404 NOT_FOUND` seems you are posting your login information somewhere that doesnt exist

Comment: @Toerktumlare I used a similar login form from [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html) I checked "view source" in a browser, and "action" in the login form was "/{my_project}/login" properly.  I didn't have any action (POST) else, except login which was provided by Spring security.  I really didn't know what caused "Completed 404 NOT_FOUND" in the action "login"

Comment: Look at this GitHub example : [SpringBootOAuth2](https://github.com/wdkeyser02/SpringBootOAuth2.git) with [Video Play list](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbuI9mmWSoUGBGKrD5W4xYVs6zdt9rW_k)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue. After comparing with a working example, I found out the bean ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy was not executed. So, within flow exchange it cannot find the session and associate the user to Anonymous.

In my case I created a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which cause issue. Instead I created an AuthenticationProvider Bean to use the user/password differently.

I found this answer useful: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68457848/1065953)